Stability for the structure sheaf
Let $X$ be say a compact Kähler manifold and $\mathcal{O}_X$ its structure sheaf. How does one argue that $\mathcal{O}_X$ is $\mu$-stable? Generally speaking, $\mu$-stability is defined only for vector bundles, but since $\mathcal{O}_X$ is locally free it should correspond to a line bundle and we should be able to calculate $$\mu(\mathcal{O}_X)=\frac{\deg(\mathcal{O}_X)}{\operatorname{rk}(\mathcal{O}_X)} = \deg(\mathcal{O}_X)=\int_Xc_1(\mathcal{O}_X)\wedge [\omega]^{n-1} = 0$$ as the corresponding line bundle to $\mathcal{O}_X$ is trivial. To obtain $\mu$-stability, one needs to argue that for any subsheaf $F\subset \mathcal{O}_X$ we have $$\mu(F)<\mu(\mathcal{O}_X).$$
There are few issues here that I'm facing. A subsheaf of a locally free sheaf doesn't need to be locally free I think. So there is the issue that $F$ could potentially not be locally free and $\mu(F)$ wouldn't make sense. The other issue is that $\mu(F)$ should be negative which I don't see how that is going to work. I recall that in some instances the slope is defined to be $-\infty$ or something, but I don't remember the definition.
What can we say here?

At least in the world of algebraic geometry, the slope is defined for an arbitrary coherent sheaf by the same $\deg/\operatorname{rk}$ formula. Whether rank is defined in general for coherent analytic sheaves I am unsure (and I guess the same question might arise around a notion of degree on a non-projective manifold).

I'm satisfied also with $X$ being smooth and projective. This should either way boil down to understanding proper subsheaves of $\mathcal{O}_X$ and I guess all of them should be torsion? @TabesBridges
